How to get total amount in one column using data tables scripts
I have lots of data one column is amount and I want to get total amount from this column.
I am trying but not getting total amount from this column using the data table script.
please give me the suggestion or one of the example.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

If you're trying, please provide a [mre] of your attempt and explain what you've done and what's been going wrong, and any debugging efforts.
